# How to set pre-selected values in Select2 APEX plugin?

Tags: jquery-select2, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a page `100` with a `Classic Report` table region `p100_report`. It renders with a query similar to this:

```
select id, pages_list from (
  select id, listagg(col_page, ':') within group (order by col_page) as pages_list
  from t1
  group by id
  order by id
) t1_lag;
```

So if `t1` is a table like this:

```
|id|col_page |
|--|---------|
| 1|      102|
| 1|      103|
| 1|      500|
| 1|      600|
| 2|      101|
| 2|      102|
| 2|      103|
```

then `t1_lag` is a table like this:

```
|id|     pages_list|
|--|---------------|
| 1|102:103:500:600|
| 2|    101:102:103|
```

Each cell in `p100_report` table, `pages_list` column contains a link to the modal page `200`. It has `Select2` Multi-select item called `p200_pages_s2`.

List of values for `p200_pages_s2`:

```
|pageID|pageName|
|------|--------|
|   100|Main    |
|   101|First   |
|   102|Second  |
|   103|Third   |
|   200|Modal   |
|   500|Admin   |
|   600|Log     |
```

It uses `pageID` for submits and `pageName` for `Select2` `li`s display correctly.

I try to send specific `page_list` values to page `200` with `Link > Target > Set Items`, assigning `\#PAGES_LIST#\` value (for example, `\101:102:103\`) to the `P200_PAGES_S2`.

In session state it has required colon separated string value, but GUI part is empty. I tried different Dynamic Actions with `Submit`, `Refresh`, even some JS code from [here](https://github.com/nbuytaert1/apex-select2/issues/77), but nothing seems to work.

**The problem**: I need to set pre-selected values in `ul.select2-selection__rendered`, add an interactive working `li` for each value from the colon separated list. Any advice?

Comment: About sending the value from one page to another may not be necessary. You can access the item on page 1 on page 99 as long as the value of the item is in the session. If do you need to send the value to another page, I think there might be a problem with the URL that is formed. Colon has a meaning in the URL of apex, I think you need to escape the values... https://community.oracle.com/thread/1064677

Comment: @romeuBraga No, afaik, that's not the problem. I'm already escaping colons with backslashes. The value transition works. The problem is that Select2 doesn't draw values as interactive list items in the form.

Comment: Are you trying to do this?
>>> https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=145797:32:0::::P32_NEW:\1:4\ <<< Please copy all the url between >>> URL  <<< In this case, i'm setting the pre-selected values to 1 and 4, you can change to values between 1..4

Comment: @romeuBraga In my case it doesn't work. Don't know why. Auto generated link doesn't look like this.

Comment: @romeuBraga If I use built-in link generator in Report Column settings, it replaces `\100:101:102\ ` with utf \ hex \ php \ idk how encoded symbols like this: `\u00255C100\u00253A101\u00253A102\u00255C`. But if I pass single value, it works despite being encoded in similar way.

Comment: I'm trying to replicate your problem, but I can't.  look at this page again, there is a report and a link, like you described, but still working https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=145797:32 If you can, access this workspace and try to replicate your problem there WORKSPACE: "stackquestions" USERNAME: "test2" PWD: "stack123" login on https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=4550:1

Comment: @romeuBraga It generates a `javascript:script` type link to a modal page.

Comment: @romeuBraga Nvm, the problem was in an incorrect Dynamic Action that was trying to set values for a plugin item. I've deleted it, and now it works as designed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in an incorrect Dynamic Action that was trying to set value with an SQL `SELECT`. I've deleted it, and now it works as designed.

I've tried to do it with SQL `SELECT` because before I was trying to set value via link, but with a comma separated set of values (e.g. `100,101,102`), and that didn't work. `Select2` understands only colon separated sets (`100:101:102`).